# How can I segue with textfield?

Tags: ios, swift

I wanted to put action to a textfield whenever a user touching textfield, segue action should be triggered immediately. But, it doesn't start segue unless after touching another object. Can you give me an idea? How can I fix it? Thank you in advance..

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking... You want a text field, but instead of editing it you want to trigger a segue to another view? Please review [ask].

Comment: Yes, i wanted to make segue with textfield instead of button click. When user touch textfield, another storyboard should be appeared without input data. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

It seems odd to want to segue when tapping a `UITextField`, but if that's what you want to do...

From the Object Library, add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the text field:

[image]

Ctrl-Drag from the newly add gesture recognizer to the target view controller and create the segue, just as you would from a button:

[image]